# Variable was unexpected this time

Tags: command-line, cmd

I am trying to run this command in command-line:

```
for /f %fpath in ('dir %1 /s /b /a-d /o:gn') do echo %fpath
```

And I get an error:

> %fpath was unexpected at this time.

What is wrong in my command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

For variable must to be one-letter variable.
This code works:

```
for /f %P in ('dir %1 /s /b /a-d /o:gn') do echo %P
```